# 2 x 2080TI GPU cards next to each other

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, fan, cooling

I have two GPUs next to each other, they are 2080TIs which are VERY thick, each is double the width of a regular card (take up two slots each). Problem is there is basically no space between them, they use fan cooling. These are the temperatures when idling.

```
Attached GPUs                       : 2
GPU 00000000:01:00.0
    Temperature
        GPU Current Temp            : 88 C
        GPU Shutdown Temp           : 94 C
        GPU Slowdown Temp           : 91 C
        GPU Max Operating Temp      : 89 C
        Memory Current Temp         : N/A
        Memory Max Operating Temp   : N/A

GPU 00000000:4D:00.0
    Temperature
        GPU Current Temp            : 56 C
        GPU Shutdown Temp           : 94 C
        GPU Slowdown Temp           : 91 C
        GPU Max Operating Temp      : 89 C
        Memory Current Temp         : N/A
        Memory Max Operating Temp   : N/A
```

So the top card is running very hot, right at the top of what is allowed. I think it is because it's fans are basically blowing into the back of the other card.

What can I do?

Comment: You can go for water cooled GPUs or vertical mounting of GPUs. This is the only possible solution other than buying a new motherboard(which is less hassle like cable managing everything again,bios updates....).

Answer (score 0):

You can get aftermarket coolers for your GPU.  I dont know if there are a lot of options for a 2080TI, as its not something I have looked into.  However, there should be fan and liquid cooling kits for them.

Alternatively and at more cost, you can get a motherboard which has the 16x PCIe slots further away from each other.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much you can do about two cards that are close to one another with regard to increasing airflow. An ideal option would be to move the cards farther apart using a lower slot on the motherboard if possible. If you are using SLI then you may need to get a larger bridge. If your motherboard cannot accommodate the cards being placed farther apart, then your only other option is custom cooling blocks for water cooling or some other form of air cooling.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the card lower down with the help of PCIE riser cable card combination.
Some server have these to move the card around, lately these were developed even more for virtual coin mining rigs to fit as many video cards as possible onto one motherboard.

Google “PCIE riser cable” and for 5-30$ you could move your card lower down, vertically or even outside the pc case if needed.

[image: PCIE riser cable]